# No matching function for call to "..." Compiler errors involving templated functions

Tags: c++, function, templates

I am working on a project where I make various algorithms such as counting and sorting for integers and then I am turning them into template functions so they can be used with things such as vectors and lists.

For example, one templated function looks like this:

```
template<typename Iter>
int count(Iter* first, Iter* limit, int value)
{
     int counter = 0;
     while(first != limit)
     {
          if(*first == value)
              ++counter;
      ++first;
     }
 return counter;
 }
```

When I run some code in my `main.cpp` such as:

```
std::vector<int> a = {0, 0, 2, 4, 2, 0};
//I expect count to return 3 for this call...
cout << count(a.begin(), a.end(), 0) << "\n";
```

It gives me a compiler error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘count(std::vector<int>::iterator, std::vector<int>::iterator, int)’
   cout << count(a.begin(), a.end(), 0) << "\n";
```

I really have tried to figure this out on my own, but it doesn't make sense to me. I have another algorithm called `print` that prints a vector from `vec.begin()` to `vec.end()` that works perfectly fine. I've tried making connections between the one that works and those that don't, but nothing makes logical sense to me.

FOLLOW UP: Could it be that the `*` in my function definitions are the problem?? Perhaps it is because I have `(Iter *first, Iter *last)` instead of `(Iter first, Iter last)`?

Comment: How did you define `Iter`?

Comment: Why is your template taking pointers to iterators? Change `iter*` --> `iter`.

Comment: @cigien I think I just discovered this (facepalm). Hopefully that resolves it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the `*` in your parameters is the problem.  An iterator is not a pointer, but is designed to *mimic* a pointer (on the other hand, a pointer can be an valid iterator).  Do not pass around iterators by pointer, pass them around by value instead, eg:

```cpp
template<typename Iter>
int count(Iter first, Iter limit, int value)
{
    int counter = 0;
    while (first != limit)
    {
        if (*first == value)
            ++counter;
        ++first;
    }
    return counter;
}
```

On a side note, the standard C++ library already has a [`std::count()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) algorithm that does the same thing your `count()` function does:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

std::vector<int> a = {0, 0, 2, 4, 2, 0};
cout << std::count(a.begin(), a.end(), 0) << "\n";
```